# jQuery issue with string split

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I have a string as below

```
var a = "M=1234&b=sdaks&c=sdkssad&strXML=<a><b mode="abc"><c>string content</c></b></a>"
```

Then I split it with **&**

```
var b = a.split('&');
```

Then further more I split b with **=** in loop and append to the form

```
$.each(b, function (index) {
        var paramsV = b[index].split('=');
        frm.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + paramsV[0] + '" value="' + paramsV[1] + '" /> ');
    });
```

But when it split with **=** that time it is splitting result string which have **=** inside the string and it is splitting that too. I would like to know how I can stop splitting the result string.

Comment: The issue is that the split string still has the '=' symbol?

Comment: Try something like `.split(/=(.+)/)`

Comment: there seems to be a typo. can show us what is your expected and current output?

Comment: I suggest to reduce your efforts by properly encoding url safe parameters, so that decoding them will be lot more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this what you want to achieve, Use `.split(/=(.+)/)` to only split the first `=`

Also notice that when you try to enter `paramsV[1]` that has a `"` inside it, it will break the original code of Input, that's why I replaces it with `.replace(/\"/g, "''")`

```js
var a = 'M=1234&b=sdaks&c=sdkssad&strXML=<a><b mode="abc"><c>string content</c></b></a>'

var b = a.split('&');
var frm = $(".frm")
$.each(b, function(index) {
  var paramsV = b[index].split(/=(.+)/);
  frm.append('<input type="" name="' + paramsV[0] + '" value="' + paramsV[1].replace(/\"/g, "''") + '" /> ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frm"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake in variable declaration. Inside double quotes you need to use single quotes. And you need to use regular expression like `.split(/=(.+)?/)`. See the output below.

```js
$(function(){
var a = "M=1234&b=sdaks&c=sdkssad&strXML=<a><b mode='abc'><c>string content</c></b></a>";
var b = a.split('&');
$.each(b, function (index) {
        var paramsV = b[index].split(/=(.+)?/);
        console.log('<input type="hidden" name="' + paramsV[0] + '" value="' + paramsV[1] + '" /> ');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what you are looking? @Milind

Comment: When I split second time with = that time if you see there is strXML, that strXML have = insdide the string which is also getting split

Comment: check now? @Milind

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "M=1234&b=sdaks&c=sdkssad&strXML=<a><b mode='abc'><c>string content</c></b></a>";
    var b = a.split('&');
    $.each(b, function (index) {
        var index1 = b[index].indexOf("=")
        var markup ='<input type="hidden" name="' + b[index].substring(0, index1) + '" value="' + b[index].substring(index1) + '" /> ';
        console.log(markup);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check it